# The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified and I NEEDto modify it

Tags: c#

**Scenario**

I am working on a program where I enter multiple IDs (they are primary keys) and enter the details once, So example if I enter PA1,PA2,and PA3, I need to save all those with the same details. To accomplish this I have passed the id into a string, then do a for each with the intention of changing the ID every loop while still entering the same details. As you can see in my code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MassCreate([Bind(Include = " refno,rec_fname,rec_lname,signature,date,time")] delivery delivery,  string hiddenIDnumber)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            hiddenIDnumber= hiddenIDnumber.Trim();

            List<string> listStrLineElements = hiddenIDnumber.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList(); 
            foreach (string str in listStrLineElements)
            { 
                 delivery.refno = str; 
                db.dbo_delivery.Add(delivery);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

          // db.dbo_delivery.Add(dbo_delivery);
           //  await db.SaveChangesAsync(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Success", "Delivery");
        }
```

**Error**
   The property 'refno' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

is the error I am getting because refno is the primary key.

In reading individuals have solved this using `Common.DataContext.Detach(object);` however I am unsure of how to implement this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating a primary key is considered very bad practice. If that value does need to change, then you should seriously consider whether that property should be used as a primary key. So you have two options:

1. Stop `refno` being a primary key and add another one (e.g. an int `Id` property). You can however give the `refno` value a unique constraint.
2. Instead of updating your entity, add a new one and delete the old one.

Comment: I would hesitate to call it "updating a primary key". I'm just changing the primary key to enter the same data for it again. In any case, how do I go about doing #2

Comment: You say you don't want to call it updating a primary key, but your next sentence sats you are just changing the primary key?!

Comment: I went and changed my primary key. much simpler